# Find the m.g.f., the mean and the variance of the aggregate claims?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, moment-generating-functions, actuarial-science, risk-assessment

Assume that the number of losses $N$ has a geometric distribution with parameter $p$, while the claim amounts,${\{X_i}\}_{i≥1}$, is a sequence of i.i.d. Gamma distributed r.v. with parameters $a$ and $b$. Find the  m.g.f.,  the  mean and  the variance  of the aggregate claims.

[Note that if $X\sim Gamma(a,b)$ then its m.g.f. is given by $m_X(z)=(\frac{b}{b-z})^a$, while if $X\sim Geometric (p)$, then $P_N(z)=\Bbb{E}(z^N)=\frac{p}{1-qz}$.]

For this question there was no mark scheme so I wanted to check whether I was right or if there was a more efficient way of solving the question.

My solution:

$$
\begin{align}
m_S(z)&= \frac{p}{1-qm_X(z)} \\
&=\frac{p}{1-q(\frac{b}{b-z})^a} \\
&=\frac{p(b-z)^a}{(b-z)^a-qb^a}
\end{align}
$$

To find the expectation and variance we need to workout $E(S)=m'_s(0)=E(X)E(N)$ and $E(S^2)=m_s''(0)$.

*I have skipped the simplification steps to save space and time

$$
\begin{align}
m'_s(z)&=\frac{apqb^a(b-z)^{a-1}}{((b-z)^a-qb^a)^2} \\
m'_s(0)&=\frac{apqb^{2a}b^{-1}}{(b^a-qb^a)^2} \\
&=\frac{a}{b}\frac{q}{p}=E(X)E(N)=E(S)
\end{align}
$$

Which gives us the expectation.

$$
\begin{align}
m''_S(z)&=\frac{apqb^a(aqb^a-qb^a+a(b-z)^a+(b-z)^a)(b-z)^{a-2}}{((b-z)^a-qb^a)^3} \\
m''_S(0)&=\frac{apqb^a(aqb^a-qb^a+ab^a+b^a)b^{a-2}}{(b^a-qb^a)^3} \\
&=\frac{aq(a-ap+p)}{b^2p^2}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $Var(S)=E(S^2)-E^2(S)$ so we get:

$$
\begin{align}
Var(S)&=\frac{aq(a-ap+p)}{b^2p^2}-\frac{a^2q^2}{b^2p^2} \\
&= \frac{a}{b^2}\frac{q}{p}
\end{align}
$$

The differentiation to do this took quite some time so I was wondering whether there was a more efficient way to solve this to avoid lots of time spent simplifying and differentiating (mainly focussed on the double prime differential to work out the variance).

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: I have doubts this is correct. Have you checked the solution?

Comment: @Dole the mark scheme showed the working to find $m_S(z)$ but after that just said to noted that $E(S)=m_S'(0)=E(X)E(N)$ and $E(S^2)=m_S''(0)$. It didn't have the final answer so I just tried to follow what they said to use in order to work it out. Even then I'm still unsure as to whether you or I are correct.

Comment: There is no way the $p$ can make it to the denominator.

Comment: @Dole $q=1-p$ for geometric distirbutions so I used this to get p on the bottom

Comment: Therefore $q-1=-p$

Comment: I think $\frac{aq(a-ap+p)}{b^2p^2}$ should be $\frac{aq(a+aq+p)}{b^2p^2}$. Then we have the same answer.

Comment: @Dole I've just redone the maths and it should be $\frac{aq(2a-ap+p)}{b^2p^2}$ and I have got the same solution as you, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$S = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$ be the aggregate claims random variable.  The gamma MGF implies the $X_i$ are parametrized by shape $a$ and rate $b$, hence $$\operatorname{E}[X_i] = a/b, \quad \operatorname{Var}[X_i] = a/b^2.$$  The geometric PGF implies $N$ has support on $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$, hence $$\operatorname{E}[N] = \frac{1-p}{p}, \quad \operatorname{Var}[N] = \frac{1-p}{p^2}.$$

Then the mean and variance of $S$ are simply
$$\operatorname{E}[S] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[S \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[N \operatorname{E}[X_1]] = \frac{a}{b} \operatorname{E}[N] = \frac{a(1-p)}{bp},$$ and
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[S] 
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[S \mid N]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[S \mid N]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[N \operatorname{Var}[X_1]] + \operatorname{Var}[N \operatorname{E}[X_1]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[N] \operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \operatorname{E}[X_1]^2 \operatorname{Var}[N] \\
&= \frac{1-p}{p} \frac{a}{b^2} + \frac{a^2}{b^2} \frac{1-p}{p^2} \\
&= \frac{a(1-p)(a + bp)}{b^2 p^2}.\\
\end{align}$$

As for the MGF, this is $$M_S(z) = \operatorname{E}[e^{zS}] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[e^{zS} \mid N]] = \operatorname{E}[(M_{X_1}(z))^N] = P_N(M_{X_1}(z)) = \frac{p}{1 - (1-p)(b/(b-z))^a}.$$  In my opinion, the use of this MGF to compute the mean and variance, although possible, is unnecessary and computationally inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it faster by noting that

$$m_S(z)=pm_G(q(\frac{b}{b-z})^\alpha),$$

where $m_G$ is the MGF for gamma with parameters 1,1.

Then (note that there may be mistakes)
$$m_S'(z)=pm_G'(q(\frac{b}{b-z})^\alpha) \alpha q(\frac{b}{b-z})^{\alpha}\frac{1}{b-z}$$
$$m_S''(z)=pm_G''(q(\frac{b}{b-z})^\alpha) (\alpha q(\frac{b}{b-z})^{\alpha}\frac{1}{b-z})^2+ pm_G'(q(\frac{b}{b-z})^\alpha) (\alpha^2+\alpha) q(\frac{b}{b-z})^{\alpha}\frac{1}{(b-z)^2}$$

$$=pm_G''(q(\frac{b}{b-z})^\alpha) (\alpha q(\frac{b}{b-z})^{\alpha}\frac{1}{b-z})^2+ m'_S(z)\frac{1+\alpha}{(b-z)}$$
And now
$$E(S)=m_S'(0)=m_G'(q) p\frac{\alpha q}{b}=\frac{1}{(1-q)^2} p\frac{\alpha q}{b}=\frac{\alpha q}{bp}$$
$$Var(S)=m_S''(0)-E(S)^2=E(S)(\frac{1+\alpha}{b}+\frac{2 \alpha q}{bp}-E(S))$$

$$=\frac{E(S)}{bp}(\alpha+p)$$